# Format a xml string in Vala?

Tags: xml, vala

Is it possible to format a xml string in Vala? I have used libxml, Xml.TextWriter class to create a xml file, but I need to create string and procces them in my program.

I want send formated string via network socket to operate them in a remote process in another host.

Using Xml.TextWriter constructor method require to determine and create a file. It seems ridiculous to read file again that only send the readed string.

Is it possible to format xml string inside Vala program?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Xml.Doc.dump_memory_format](http://valadoc.org/libxml-2.0/Xml.Doc.dump_memory_format.html).  There is an [example in C](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/io2.c) on libxml's web site, for Vala it would be something like:

```
Xml.Doc doc = ...;
string xml_string;
int xml_string_len;

doc.dump_memory_format (out xml_string, out xml_string_len);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can use [SaveCtxt](http://valadoc.org/#!api=libxml-2.0/Xml.SaveCtxt), which uses callbacks. Thought the binding for `xmlOutputWriteCallback` seems to be missing the first argument containing the context. Might be easiest to do this in C and pass the result back into Vala.